# Hide alt tags to users on images, but keep them in the code for SEO

Tags: html

My website has a lot of big images (it is a t-shirt shop). I have added revelant keywords to `<alt>` tags for SEO purposes. The problem is that when the images are loading, the `<alt>` tags are displayed to the users and it looks really ugly because the `<alt>` tags are really long.

[image: Check screenshot to see the problem]

Is there a way to hide the `<alt>` tags from the user but keep them in the code to help search engine rankings?

Comment: How can we figure out what is actually displayed on the broken image without seeing your code?

Comment: The image is not broken, it is loading. The question is about hiding ALT tags when the image is loading.

Comment: Solutions for you in answers below.

Comment: Ouch... you know that by keyword stuffing like that, you are probably making the site nearly unusable for disabled screenreader users? http://webaim.org/techniques/screenreader/ - typically, any behaviour that hurts users ends up being penalised by Google, in a future update if not now.

Comment: Have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72516859/6666348

Answer (score 6):

The alt attribute is not a place to stuff keywords, and doing so will cause search engines to *penalise* you. It is supposed to contain a short *replacement* for the image. Use it correctly and it will look a lot less ugly.

Comment: That's not the question i asked. I don't care wether it looks ugly or not, i don't want any text to display when the image is loading.

Answer (score 2):

If you need a javascript solution, user spezzino gave you one. BUT this will only work if it is actually the html image alt attribute displayed and not it's title. Also, using javascript to remove those attributes is the most efficient technique to avoir bad page ranking or search-engines penalties.

If you need a css solution :
    *This works, but will penalize your page ranking for 'spamming' techniques.*

```
img {color:transparent;background-color:transparent}
```

[jsFiddled with your code for example](http://jsfiddle.net/rj593/)

If you need a firefox specif solution:

```
img:-moz-broken {color:transparent;background-color:transparent;}
```

If you want a solution only for YOUR work station :

```
Try to set the Boolean pref browser.display.show_image_placeholders to false on the about:config page.
```

Also, take note that we are NOT able to figure out if it is the 'title' or the 'alt' attribute displayed. This is why we ask for your html. To get a better understanding of your situation without having to 'try' answers on what we thing your situation is.

Comment: Sorry, but you are asking me to go see the live page's coding without providing it within your question. This is out of Stackoverflow rules of conduct. Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results. J'ai fait de mon mieux pour t'aider. Salutations,

Comment: YOU are the one who asked me to see my code. 500 characters limit isn't enough to post it so i provided the live URL. I already posted attempted solution and expected results. Your reply is useless.

Comment: Solutions for you in answers. Don't be offenced, but your question is just an image. You have there (in your question, not a comment) more than 500 characters to post your code and demonstrate what you've tried. Peu importe, les solutions sont affichées dans nos réponses. Tu as tout ce qui te faut pour continuer.

Comment: Et un conseil de développeur : valide ton code [224 Errors, 13 warning(s) ] : http://validator.w3.org/check?verbose=1&uri=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com%2F  Ça joue aussi sur le 'page ranking'

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery [removeAttr()](http://api.jquery.com/removeattr/) to delete *alt* atribute

```
$("img").each(function(index, image){
    $(image).removeAttr("alt");
});
```

Be sure to include that snippet inside  $(document).ready() function

Comment: I added the code to my website but it didn't work :( http://manches-longues.ni-dieu-ni-maitre.com/l-revolution-espagnole-C85433

Answer (score 0):

**dirty way**
use CSS:

```css
img{
    color:#fff;/*or transparent*/
    background-color:#fff;
    background-image:url('your loading image');
}
```