# Replace invalid image in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my website, there is an `<img />` element without `src` attribute. It's `src` is set dynamically with Javascript after a while. In chrome, it is hidden, but in firefox it shows me up this:

[image: image brack]

Is here any way how to get rid of this via any HTML attribute or even CSS? I could do this with JS to append this `img` element after loading image or changing image.

**can I do it with something easier than with JS?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As found in another answer: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html-without-js)

```
<img src="Error.src" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
```

**Edit**
I know it is still javascript, but the easiest solution I've found.

Comment: Thanks! Long time ago I found that `onerror` event, but I was unable to find that question on google again. Great, haven't tested yet, but I think it will works.