# HTML email hide broken image icon

Tags: html, css, email

In most of my emails, the image included may not be present. In such cases the broken image icon is displayed along with my `alt` text.

**Problem Explanation:**
While sending an HTML email along with an `<img>` tag, at cases this image **may not be there (404)**. As the image URL is dynamic, I cannot verify the existence of the image before sending the email. So it displays a **broken image icon**. I want to get rid of this icon.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/saravanan9006/4cqkwybs/)

Code Snippet:

```
<img alt="NA" src="http://www.somerandomdomain.com/error.png" width="120"  >
```

I am need of a solution compatible with all major email clients.

- Have tried `onerror` handler, but it does not work in email clients.
- Also have tried `text-indent: -9999px;`, it works in Outlook but not
  in Gmail.
- When the negative indent is changed to positive Outlook
  scrolls to the right which is a mess.

The solutions mentioned in [possible duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html-without-js), are for the web. But my question is clearly about the **HTML emails**, where JS and objects does not work like the solutions provided.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? I don't know what the question is.

Comment: @PatrickMlr, I have images in email which may be broken at times. But I do not want to display the image broken icon in the place.

Comment: specify your problem in brief

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to hide image broken Icon using only CSS/HTML (without js)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html-without-js)

Comment: @developernator, the solutions mentioned **does not work with email clients**.

Answer (score 0):

When generating email, check if that image exists *(Example in PHP)*:

```
$url = 'http://www.somerandomdomain.com/error.png';
$headers = @get_headers($url);

if (strpos($headers[0],'200') !== false) {
    echo "<img alt='NA' src='{$url}' width='120'/>";
}
```