# Hide broken image link in Semantic UI React

Tags: javascript, html, image, reactjs, semantic-ui

I've created an [image](https://react.semantic-ui.com/elements/image) element using Semantic UI React.

```html
<Image floated="right" size="mini" src="/someImageUrl.png" />
```

If the image's `src` property doesn't load, a broken image placeholder is displayed instead.

[image]

How can I hide this broken image placeholder and show no image instead when my image doesn't load?

I've tried following the answer from [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html-without-js) which suggests using

```
<Image src="Error.src" onerror="this.style.display='none'"/>
```

But I receive the error `Expected 'onError' listener to be a function.`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can pass the `img` element to an `onError` handler through the handler event's `target` property, and change the image's `src` to `''` or `style.display` to `none`.

```html
<Image src={imageObject.Url} onError={i => i.target.src=''} />
```

```html
<Image src={imageObject.Url} onError={i => i.target.style.display='none'} />
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use:

```
<Image src={imageObject.Url} onError={e => e.target.style.display = 'none'} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a problem where the img icon is rendered with src =  "". Because of an initial state source which I set to empty strings

In the useEffect / (Component Did Mount). I update that state to the desired url.

The problem is the broken img icon stays while the url is being downloaded.

Also the onError={} doesn't trigger.

The solution was a conditional render.

```
{ 
source === "" ? null : <Img src={source} onError={someMethod} /> 
}
```