# #document inside <object> on broken [src]

Tags: html, image, onerror

I am trying to deal with broken images to get a nice and clean result. What I want is:

1. To get rig of the broken image icon.
2. To be able to define my own default content, image or text, and style it.

I am using React, but I think this is related to HTML only. Also, I am currently using Chrome, but I'm looking for a result working on all main browsers.

I know I can use an `img` tag with `onError` method:

```
<img
    src="wrongUrl"
    onError={(e) => {
        e.target.src = 'https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals';
    }}
/>
```

This works great for images. But I want to understand how that can be done with an `object` tag.

Reading [How to hide image broken Icon using only CSS/HTML (without js)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html-without-js/32928240#32928240) I found out that there are two ways:

A. Using onError method:

```
<object
    data="wrongUrl"
    type="image/jpg"
    onError={(e) => {
        e.target.src = "https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals";
    }}
/>
```

B. Wrapping a default element within our `object` tag:

```
<object
    data="wrongUrl"
    type="image/jpg"
>
    <img src="wrongUrl" />
</object>
```

But in both cases, there are some situations when a `#document` element is inserted inside the `object`, like this:

```
<object data="wrongUrl" type="image/jpg">
    #document
    <!doctype html>
    <html>…</html>
    <img src="https://placeimg.com/200/300/animals">
</object>
```

This `#document` element is in fact the document element of my page, so it is inserted inside `object` tag as a default content.

I would like to understand how `#document` element is inserted here, and why it is conflicting with my default element.

Comment: "This #document element is in fact the document element of my page" — Are you sure it is not a different object? (`document`, while being a DOM node, is not an element)

Comment: "why it is conflicting with my default element" — What makes you think it is **conflicting**?

Comment: @Quentin I'm asking because I'm not sure what is this #document element, and I don't know which term use for it. I say that is «conflicting» because it renders a copy of the website inside object element, and over the default img element.