# Remove wire frame around image when it is lazy loading

Tags: html, css

I'm lazy loading some website's favicons. When they're lazy loading, a wire frame appears around the loading image (see to the left of nutrition.gov in the image). How do I prevent this wire frame/outline from appearing around a loading image?

[image]

```
.icon {
    height: 16px;
    width: 16px;
    outline: none;
}

<script>
        function hideIcon(img){
            img.onerror = null;
            img.style.display = "none";
        }
</script>

<img class="icon" src="https://www.nutrition.gov/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16" loading="lazy" onerror="hideIcon()">

    <img class="icon" src="https://www.nutrition.gov/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16" loading="lazy" onerror="hideIcon()">

   <img class="icon" src="https://www.nutrition.gov/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16" loading="lazy" onerror="hideIcon()">

    <img class="icon" src="https://www.nutrition.gov/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16" loading="lazy" onerror="hideIcon()">

<img class="icon" src="https://www.nutrition.gov/favicon.ico" height="16" width="16" loading="lazy" onerror="hideIcon()">
```

Comment: Is this happening *only* on FF mobile?

Comment: Happens with all mobile browsers. Edited my post to reflect that

Comment: That's just the default behavior for when the link to the image is broken.  https://www.nutrition.gov/favicon.ico is 404.  That's your real issue. ;)

Comment: I see. Is it possible to prevent the outline from appearing as part of that behavior? I use an onerror function to hide the broken links, but for a split second you still see the wire frame appear and it's really ugly.

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html) have a lot of answers that are very useful.