# How to hide image broken Icon using only CSS/HTML and without using display: none?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I can't hide image broken icon. If I display none, it will not display my css.

```
 <img 
        className="card__image" 
        src={image ? image : ""}
        alt={name || ""}
      />
```

I want to remove just broken icon without touching css
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/triMn.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the valid way to include an image with no src?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5775469/whats-the-valid-way-to-include-an-image-with-no-src)

Comment: what do you mean by hiding image broken link? You can hide the whole img element of course both using or `display: none` or `visibility: hidden`. The former will just ignore the whole element in the document flow, the latter will hide the element but the document flow will take into account its size (assuming you set one). Otherwise maybe you meant to have a fallback?

Comment: Here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/980855/inputting-a-default-image-in-case-the-src-attribute-of-an-html-img-is-not-vali you will find how to deal with a fallback picture in case

Comment: Plenty of good answers here too: [How to hide image broken Icon using only CSS/HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html)

Comment: @DiegoD Thank you for suggestions. Actually, I did figure it out. Other approaches may render it slowly in large-scale projects. I went with below options in answer section.

Comment: @Stefnotch Thank you for the reply. Yes, it did, but I wanted to use better method, so it wouldn't render it slowly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{image && name ? (
        <img
          className="card__image"
          src={image}
          alt={name}
        />
      ) : (
        <div className="card__image"></div>
      )}
```

This approach worked for me. Thank you, I just figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways are existsing to hide elems in css instead `display: none`

Use:
`opacity: 0;` to make elem disappear but it remains to be interactive

Or use:
`visibility: hidden` to hide that.

> Use `pointer-events: none` to make it non-interactive

Comment: It is deleting my css background color

Comment: he is asking to hide broken image icon which appers when image is not found and not the entire image itself

Comment: well, I have css properties on that img tag. I'm getting empty area.