# Remove the break icon in the img element without deleting that element

Tags: html, css

I tried to remove the broken icon in the img element when the destination url doesn't exist, without deleting the img element :

HTML:

```
<img src="error.png">
```

CSS:

```
img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(url.png);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Instead of deleting the img element, I prefer to bring up the background-img without a broken icon.

I hope someone help me, I really need this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html You can find your solution in above thread.

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer I found on Stack Overflow, try using `img:after` in combination with the `content` property.
[How to hide image broken Icon using only CSS/HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22051573/how-to-hide-image-broken-icon-using-only-css-html#answer-37192970)

```
img:after {  
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: url(url.png);
  content: '';
}
```

Here you can find the working example: https://codepen.io/filipalbert/pen/QWZxPMp

Answer (score 0):

You can use `::before` and `::after` for this.

Something like this:

```css
img {
  position: relative;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}

img::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://via.placeholder.com/200);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<img src="wrong_link">
<img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200">
```

Comment: I've tried it, but the broken icon is still there with a border

Comment: @NurvyGamedev does this snippet works for you here ?